# Recreate input with LSTM autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, autoencoder

I am trying to use LSTMs to encode my input data and then decode/recreate it from the encoded data. I have a few 100 samples to run through with 40 timesteps each and 1260 features.
My rough idea of how the network will look is the following. Inputing the data into an LSTM layer, encoding it into the dense layer then using the final LSTM as an output layer.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(40, 1260), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='softmax'))
model.add(LSTM(1260))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(input_train, input_test, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

I've played around with different dimension sizes and number of hidden layers but I can't get the accuracy anywhere close than 1% or so.
Thanks in advance

Updated code:

```
timesteps = 40
features = 1260

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, input_shape=(timesteps,features)))
model.add(RepeatVector(timesteps))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(features)))
model.add(LSTM(1260, return_sequences=True))
model.summary()
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(input_train, input_test, epochs=200, batch_size=16, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

glass3,

Most likely the error caused by introduction of `Dense` layer without spreading its values across time. In most LSTM Autoencoder structures I observe use of `keras.layers.RepeatVector()` after the encoder and `keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense())` after the decoder. Try replicating the structures from examples and then gradually modify them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I did some reading on TimeDistributed and RepeatVectors and am now getting roughly 10% accuracy with the updated code. I updated it in my original post. Do you have any advice for improving accuracy?

Comment: You have too few samples and too many features for high accuracy. Try getting more data or testing your structure on longer dataset. 
Would you accept the answer for now?